# Use insta for approval testing of binary output

Tags: rust, approval-tests

I'm writing a library that will generate binary pdf-files based on some input. I'd like to use the `insta` crate since it seems to do basically what I want. However, it doesn't seem to support arbitrary binary files, just json/yaml and a few others.

This is what I have so far, which would technically work, but I can't review the actual pdf:

```rust
let mut content: Vec<u8> = vec![];
let Ok(x) = to_pdf(&document, &mut content) else { todo!() };

assert_eq!(x, ());
assert_debug_snapshot!("generated_document", &content)
```

Where `to_pdf` has this signature:

```rust
pub fn to_pdf(document: &Document, mut w: impl Write) -> Result<(), io::Error>
```

**Is there a way to make it compare the content of generated pdf files while also outputting the pdf in a fairly easily reviewable form?**

Comment: I do not get what you mean by "fairly easily reviewable form". If you want to view the PDF in a viewer simply write the `content` to a _xy.pdf_ file.

Comment: Ideally the  snapshot would be the pdf file. The test output could then highlight the contents that differ between the runs (possibly ignoring offsets and some other not super important things). I'm guessing this isn't possible currently.